# VMWare 15, sharing folder with guest OS

Tags: vmware, ubuntu-20.04, guest

VMWare: 15.5.0 build-14665864

A simple `cp localfolder ~/shares/share-folder/` would fail with an error, when attempted using e.g. gnome-files (nautilus) the error states "slicing error".

The share has been mounted according to e.g.
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the virtual machine, Ubuntu 20.04

```
$ sudo umount shares
$ tail -n 1 /etc/fstab 
vmhgfs-fuse     /home/hannu/shares fuse    defaults,max_write=32768,allow_other      0    0
$ mkdir -p $HOME/shares && sudo mount shares
```

Make sure that the fstab line has max_write defined as above.
The name of the folder you have defined as "share" in VMWare settings (for the current VM) will appear as a sub-folder in ~/shares/ .